# Zathura goto real page number

Tags: zathura

Some PDFs include metadata about their pages as to the real page number. For instance C1 for the cover page and roman numerals for the preface. Zathura displays these just fine, but right now commands like :1 goes to the cover page, i.e. absolute page 1, and I'd like to be able to go to the page whose metadata says it's page 1 (rather than C1) and fallback to absolute page numbers if no metadata is available. Is this possible?

Comment: What about https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/hub/how-to/add-page-numbers-to-a-pdf (https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=PDF%20page%20numbers)?

Comment: [I reported an issue for this.](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/-/issues/363)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a clean solution to this problem but I do have a work-around. Set
a bookmark at page 0. You can do this by going to page 0 and running `bmark a`.
This creates a bookmark which is stored in

> ~/.local/share/zathura/bookmarks.

So every time you open the file you will have
access to that bookmark by running `blist a`.

Now create a mapping in your zathurarc to navigate to the bookmark. One
way to do this is by including `map u feedkeys ":blist a <Return>"` in your
zathurarc file.

To navigate to page x type `uxJ`. Here `J` is the default mapping to go down
one page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `offset` to set the real page number and `gg` to go to the first page (usually cover page). Thus if the first page is on page 17, `1G` will take you there if you set the offset and `gg17JK` or `gg16J` will also take you to the same page.